# PHP session not working after upgrading

Tags: php, session, authentication

Good morning folds!

I'm stuck and need your expertise :)

I have been using the following open source login script for several years now: https://github.com/panique/php-login-advanced (I have customized a few things however the login/process/registration script remains the same.

Recently I have moved all my files to a new server that runs on PHP 5.6.28 and the Login sessions stopped working (registrations still work and login users are properly showing in mysql) however php session doesn't detect the user as logged in, if I move the identical files back to the old server everything works.

I was told that for security purposes something changed in the last PHP upgrade but I cannot find what part of code I need to change/adapt for the session variables to be passed properly.

Is it possible that something in the part attached is failing?

```
         /* Class constructor */
   function Process(){
      global $session;
      /* User submitted login form */
      if(isset($_POST['sublogin'])){
         $this->procLogin();
      }


/* ProcLogin */
   function procLogin(){
      global $session, $form;
      /* Login attempt */
      $retval = $session->login($_POST['user'], $_POST['pass'], isset($_POST['remember']));

      /* Login successful */
      if($retval){
         header("location:dashboard.php");
      }
      /* Login failed */
      else{
         $_SESSION['value_array'] = $_POST;
         $_SESSION['error_array'] = $form->getErrorArray();
         header("location:failed.php");
      }
   }
```

OR

```
   function startSession(){
      global $database;  //The database connection
      session_start();   //Tell PHP to start the session

      /* Determine if user is logged in */
      $this->logged_in = $this->checkLogin();

      /**
       * Set guest value to users not logged in, and update
       * active guests table accordingly.
       */
      if(!$this->logged_in){
         $this->username = $_SESSION['username'] = GUEST_NAME;
         $this->userlevel = GUEST_LEVEL;
         $database->addActiveGuest($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $this->time);
      }
      /* Update users last active timestamp */
      else{
         $database->addActiveUser($this->username, $this->time);
      }

      /* Remove inactive visitors from database */
      $database->removeInactiveUsers();
      $database->removeInactiveGuests();

      /* Set referrer page */
      if(isset($_SESSION['url'])){
         $this->referrer = $_SESSION['url'];
      }else{
         $this->referrer = "/";
      }

      /* Set current url */
      $this->url = $_SESSION['url'] = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
   }
```

Comment: There are few things i can recommend..
create a simple test page :-
     <?php
      session_start();
      $_SESSION['test-available'] = "im testing session working";
      echo "<pre>";
      print_r($_SESSION);
     ?>

     this will confirm session infact is working on the server...

if not , then check , if you have enough space available for file creation because once i had the issue and there was 0 bytes available hence was unable to create the session because sessions are file created holding all data whose path is mentioned in php.ini... 

hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you @Ahmad. I gave that a shot and getting a response, however it's showing me as a guest instead of the actual username that I'm logged in under: devilmike90.

Array
(
    [username] => Guest
    [url] => /Quote/index.php
    [test-available] => im testing session working
)

Comment: could you try to inspect this method $session->login() use "die;" there to stop and view session e.g

function login($a,$b,$c,$d)
{
     $_SESSION['a'] = $a;
     print_r($_SESSION);
     die;
     .........
}

dat will confirm if session is accessible and started in that method...

Comment: The URL to the scrip used above it incorrect, I meant I'm using this one: https://github.com/praveenvvstgy/php-login-script

Comment: Sorry @Ahmad, I'm not fully sure what you mean.

Comment: I added another piece of code above that might be causing issues explaining why any user that logs in is always detected as a GUEST. Can you see a problem?

Comment: goto that class $session class and there you will find that method "login" where you can follow my steps because i donno which class $session is object of...  :)

refering to : $session->login($_POST['user'], $_POST['pass'], isset($_POST['remember']));

Comment: This section you are talking about? (Thank you for trying hehe :))

function startSession(){
      global $database; 
      session_start();  
      $this->logged_in = $this->checkLogin();

      if(!$this->logged_in){
         $this->username = $_SESSION['username'] = GUEST_NAME;
         $this->userlevel = GUEST_LEVEL;
         $database->addActiveGuest($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $this->time);
      }

Comment: check this line :
      $retval = $session->login($_POST['user'], $_POST['pass'], isset($_POST['remember']));

here you see , "login" function is called , and you will have to begin debugging from there  ( according to me )

Comment: OK, so I took a look at the code step by step and retval from above does work because the "if($retval){ header("location:dashboard.php"); is sending me to the dashboard, BUT the session information doesn't seem to be retained and is sending me in a GUEST.

      if(!$this->logged_in){
         $this->username = $_SESSION['username'] = GUEST_NAME;
         $this->userlevel = GUEST_LEVEL;

Comment: From reading, it seems to be related to the latest PHP upgrade but I'm really not sure what to look for... the code exact code of my session page is: https://github.com/praveenvvstgy/php-login-script/blob/master/include/session.php

Comment: change this 

function startSession(){
      global $database;  //The database connection
      session_start();   //Tell PHP to start the session

----TO----
function startSession(){
      global $database;  //The database connection
      session_id("testing-issue");
      session_start();   //Tell PHP to start the session

Comment: change this in login() function :-
$this->username  = $_SESSION['username'] = $this->userinfo['username'];
      $this->userid    = $_SESSION['userid']   = $this->generateRandID();
----TO----
 $_SESSION['username'] = $this->userinfo['username'];
 $this->username  = $_SESSION['username'] ;
 $_SESSION['userid']   = $this->generateRandID();
 $this->userid    = $_SESSION['userid'];
 
 print_r($_SESSION);
 die;

Comment: @Ahmad, thank you so much once again for helping :) I did what you suggested and got the variable properly posted in the array echo however I'm not that much an expert to know what that means:

Array ( [username] => devilmike90 [url] => /Quote/process.php [userid] => c6d1a65eeb12ddebe30f9870220dab81 )

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure what happened, but it appears that it's now working :|

I logged in one with the code modified which stalled at the array echo, I removed the code and now am able to properly login?!?! Haha.

Comment: did u sent session id explicitly using session_id() ?

if it worked then its all fine...

Comment: Yes, @Ahmad. Thank you very much for all your helps, I'm so happy that I can continue to work on my site :) :) :)

Comment: thats gr8 to hear :)